# Text to dictionary doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following text file in the same folder as my Python Code.

```
78459581
Black Ballpoint Pen
12345670
Football
49585922
Perfume
83799715
Shampoo
```

I have written this Python code.

```
file = open("ProductDatabaseEdit.txt", "r")
d = {}
for line in file:
    x = line.split("\n")
    a=x[0]
    b=x[1]
    d[a]=b

print(d)
```

This is the result I receive.

```
b=x[1]  # IndexError: list index out of range
```

My dictionary should appear as follows:

```
{"78459581" : "Black Ballpoint Pen"
 "12345670" : "Football"
 "49585922" : "Perfume"
 "83799715" : "Shampoo"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bob, for those of us who are not clairvoyant, it may be clearer if you describe what you wish to accomplish in the first paragraph{.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip the \n, not split

```
file = open("products.txt", "r")
d = {}
for line in file:
    a = line.strip()
    b = file.next().strip()
    # next(file).strip() # if using python 3.x
    d[a]=b

print(d)

{'12345670': 'Football', '49585922': 'Perfume', '78459581': 'Black Ballpoint Pen', '83799715': 'Shampoo'}
```

Comment: Your solution provides this error... `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: It produced the results shown. hmm.  I used  python 2.7

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 (or something close to it)

Comment: I found this: In Python 3, use `next(file)` instead of `file.next()`.

Comment: It works, but this gives me the next error. `StopIteration` for the line `b = next(file).strip()`

Comment: I just changed my code and ran with python 3.4.  I didn't get that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116926/discussion-between-joel-goldstick-and-bob-smith).

Answer (score 5):

A line is terminated by a linebreak, thus `line.split("\n")` will never give you more than one line.

You could cheat and do:

```
for first_line in file:
    second_line = next(file)
```

Comment: I'd not call it cheating, by the way ;-) Using `next()` is an excellent solution.

Comment: I called it cheating, because it breaks if the assumption (even number of lines) is violated. But I guess in that case, unless something is planned specifically, it *should* break.

Comment: Exactly; and you can always use `next(file, <default value>)` if a missing last line is not an error.

Comment: Actually, it probably (haven't tested it) won't break, since `next(file)` will raise `StopIteration` and just break out of the loop.

Comment: @L3viathan this is what I have done. `for first_line in file: [NEW LINE]
    second_line = next(file) [NEW LINE]
    d[first_line] = second_line` but this gives me this dictionary: `'78459581\n': 'Black Ballpoint Pen \n'` - how do I remove the `\n`?

Comment: @BobSmith: use `str.rstrip()`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your solution by using a [dictionary generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), this is probably the most pythonic solution I can think of:

```
>>> with open("in.txt") as f:
...   my_dict = dict((line.strip(), next(f).strip()) for line in f)
... 
>>> my_dict
{'12345670': 'Football', '49585922': 'Perfume', '78459581': 'Black Ballpoint Pen', '83799715': 'Shampoo'}
```

Where `in.txt` contains the data as described in the problem. It is necessary to `strip()` each line otherwise you would be left with a trailing `\n` character for your keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

## What's going on

When you open a file you get an iterator, which will give you one line at a time when you use it in a *for* loop.

Your code is iterating over the file, splitting every line in a list with `\n` as the delimiter, but **that gives you a list with only one item**: the same line you already had. Then **you try to access the second item in the list, which doesn't exist.** That's why you get the `IndexError: list index out of range`.

## How to fix it

What you need is this:

```
file = open('products.txt','r')
d = {}
for line in file:
    d[line.strip()] = next(file).strip()
```

In every loop you add a new key to the dictionary (by assigning a value to a key that didn't exist yet) and assign the next line as the value. The `next()` function is just telling to the `file` iterator *"please move on to the next line"*. So, to drive the point home: in the first loop you set first line as a key and assign the second line as the value; in the second loop iteration, you set the third line as a key and assign the fourth line as the value; and so on.

The reason you need to use the `.strip()` method every time, is because your example file had a space at the end of every line, so that method will remove it.

## Or...

You can also get the same result using a **dictionary comprehension**:

```
file = open('products.txt','r')
d = {line.strip():next(file).strip() for line in file}
```

Basically, is a shorter version of the same code above. It's shorter, but less readable: not necessarily something you want (a matter of taste).

Answer (score 0):

In my solution i tried to not use any loops. Therefore, I first load the txt data with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("test.txt", header = None)
```

Then I seperate keys and values for the dict such as:

```
keys, values = file[0::2].values, file[1::2].values
```

Then, we can directly zip these two as lists and create a dict:

```
result = dict(zip(list(keys.flatten()), list(values.flatten())))
```

To create this solution I used the information as provided in [question]: [How to remove every other element of an array in python? (The inverse of np.repeat()?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777482/how-to-remove-every-other-element-of-an-array-in-python-the-inverse-of-np-repe) and in [question]: [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python#209854)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a list two items at a time:

```
file = open("ProductDatabaseEdit.txt", "r")
data = file.readlines()
d = {}

for line in range(0,len(data),2):
    d[data[i]] = data[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (where the data is in */tmp/tmp5.txt*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

d = dict()
iskey = True
with open("/tmp/tmp5.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if iskey:
            _key = line.strip()
        else:
            _value = line.strip()
            d[_key] = _value
        iskey = not iskey

print(d)
```

Which gives you:

```
{'12345670': 'Football', '49585922': 'Perfume', '78459581': 'Black Ballpoint Pen', '83799715': 'Shampoo'}
```